# Eine Frage zum Wort "Spaßfabrik"

Tags: word-usage

I (vaguely) recall reading once that the word "Spaßfabrik" can be used to refer to someone that tends to be funny and/or joke around. Can any of you provide me with examples of its usage?

Comment: If I google this, I get links to all sorts of family fun parks … which I expected from the term *Spaßfabrik*. It's a former factory turned into a fun location.

Comment: I’ve never heard it before, neither in the sense you imply nor in the sense Janka implies. The mighty search engine supports Janka’s statement. However, if the term were used for a person, I’d probably understand it in context (but not without, and it would still sound artificial).

Comment: @Janka: Not necessary a former factory. Just something (or someone? -- not sure) that **produces** fun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never heard this term before, but even without any context it seems to be clear what it means. The english translation is

> fun factory

and like you can guess the meaning of this english term without any context, you can do the same for the German *»Spaßfabrik«*.

It can be:

- A person who is funny and makes jokes all the time.
- An organization or a company whose goal is to entertain people.

If you search the internet for the German term *»Spaßfabrik«* you will find fun parks who have this word in their name. But although I never have heard this word before, I also would find it appropriate to use it for a person who is permanently funny.

Comment: A related term (common although a bit outdated) for a person who does this at the work place is *Betriebsnudel*.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Ohne Beschränkung auf die Arbeitswelt: *Ulknudel*